# MvcHtmlString.ToString is escaping the text in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to change the `DisplayFor` output (format the string), but the output string has an ampersand. How can I handle the `MvcHtmlString` to not escape the ampersand?

This is the code in the cshtml file:

```
@{
    string title = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Entity.Description).ToString();
    if (Model.City != null)
        title = String.Format("{0} em {1}", title, Model.Entity.CityName);
    ViewBag.Title = title;
}
```

The model.Entity.Description has value `"Automóvel"` in the database. But the output is rendered in html as `Autom&#243;vel`. Here is the html output:

```
<p>Autom&amp;#243;vel</p>
```

If I try to use `Html.Raw()` in  the `ViewBag.Title`, the title is not shown.

**Edit: Added more details**

Even if I try the suggested approach of using this code, the `ViewBag.Title` does not display it. Here is the modified code after comments:

```
@{
    string title = Model.Entity.Description;
    if (Model.City != null)
    { 
        title = String.Format("{0} em {1}", Model.Entity.Description,
            Model.Entity.CityName);
    }
    ViewBag.Title = Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(title));
}
```

Comment: Why are you even doing `DisplayFor` here? Why not just use `model.Entity.Description`?

Comment: @DavidG, you are right. This way it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to interfere with the title in any way, just assign it directly:

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.Entity.Description;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to decode it.

```
 @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Entity.Description));
```

Comment: This code `ViewBag.Title = Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(title));` does not work. `string title = "Autom&#243;vel";`.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. DavidG is correct. You don't need `@Html.DisplayFor` on a title, since it's not HTML. If you were experiencing the issue in the layout of the page, then that's where this would be useful.